# Using the value of a dictionary as the key in another dictionary, and the frequency of the key as the value, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the dictionary:

`CodonDict = {'ATT':'I',   'ATC':'I',  'ATA':'I',  'CTT':'L',  'CTC':'L',...}` The dictionary continues for 64 other unique triplets.

I'm iterating through a text file which is essentially one giant string. My code right now updates the empty dictionary with 64 entries with the keys as from 0 to 63:

`TripletCount = {0: 18626, 1: 9187, 2: 9273, 3: 9154, 4: 37129, 5: 36764, 6: 18468,...}`, with the value being the frequency of the triplet (with the key being in an integer however).

`TripletCount = {}`

I would like to use the **values** of `CodonDict` as the key in `TripletCount` with the frequency of the key as the value in `TripletCount`.

I've programmed in python before but formatting dictionaries has never been my strong suit.

The data file I'm iterating though looks essentially like this:

`'GTGGCTTCTCTTCTCCACTCCTCTTTTTATTCCTTCCCAAACAAGAAGGTTAGTTATTATTATTTCCAGA...'`

EDIT:

An example of what I'm trying to get;

`TripletCount = {'I': 18626, 'V': 9187, 'L': 9273, 'Y': 9154, 'E': 37129,...}`

EDIT 2:

As per request: I plan on resolving key conflicts by adding the counts to lists as  different types of base pairs can identify the same amino acid, so `{'I': [18626, 9187, 9154], ...}`

Comment: Can you add an example of the result you want?

Comment: Yes of course: `TripletCount = {'I': 18626, 'V': 9187, 'L': 9273, 'Y': 9154,...}`

Comment: As for me, it will be difficult to transform your dict right now. Instead, you can try to insert codons as the keys during the parsing of the DNA string. Can you also add a code that generates `TripletCount` dict?

Comment: Your sample values of `CodonDict` are not unique, so how do you plan to resolve key conflicts when these values become keys?

Comment: @Oleksander Thats what Id like to know how to do, is there a way to "append" the values as the keys in another dict? All while the other dict makes sure the base pairs (like AAT etc) still dictate the frequency of the key in the other dictionary, if that makes sense?

Comment: @blhsing, Thats the question, if there is a way to use just one dictionary I would much prefer that, but the only way that I can think of doing that would be to hard code it.

Comment: Two typical ways to resolve key conflicts are: 1) summing up the counts (so `{'I': 18626 + 9187 + 9154, ...`), 2) turning the counts into a list (so `{'I': [18626, 9187, 9154], ...}`) Please update your question with how you plan to resolve key conflicts after you've made the decision.

Comment: @SeabassGoslin you can use a structure like `{"ATT": {"acid": "I", "frequency": 18626}, ...}`.

Comment: @blhsing Ill use your second method by turning the counts into a list, as different base pairs can be used to identify an amino acid (the new key) so `{'I': [18626, 9187, 9154], ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through your data, looking at three sequential characters at a time and checking if each string of three characters is a key in your `CodonDict` dictionary. If it is, you can increment the value of `TripletCount`.

For example, using your sample dataset from the question:

```
CodonDict = {'ATT':'I',   'ATC':'I',  'ATA':'I',  'CTT':'L',  'CTC':'L'}
TripletCount = {}
data = 'GTGGCTTCTCTTCTCCACTCCTCTTTTTATTCCTTCCCAAACAAGAAGGTTAGTTATTATTATTTCCAGA'

for i in range(3, len(data)): # iterates through your data string 
    triplet = CodonDict.get(data[i-3:i]) # check if the next 3 characters in a row are a key in CodonDict
    if triplet: # if it is a key: increment the count of its value by one
        TripletCount[triplet] = TripletCount.get(triplet, 0) + 1

print(TripletCount)
{'I': 4, 'L': 8}
```

Comment: WOW thank you, this negated the two days I spent on this, it works!! Thanks again!

Comment: You could also use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which is reportedly much faster for counting things instead of the regular dictionary +1 method.

Comment: @arjoonn You could use `Counter`, I'm not sure how much this buys you in this case though because you still have to iterate over the `data` string. You could do something like `Counter(CodonDict.get(data[i-3:i]) for i in range(3, len(data)))` and then remove/ignore the `None` key.

Answer (score 0):

Keys are unique in a dictionary, so in `TripletCount` every value will equal `1`.
Correct me if I misunderstood your question.

The following code may solve your problem by using defaultdict of defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict as ddict


CodonDict = {'ATT':'I',   'ATC':'I',  'ATA':'I',  'CTT':'L',  'CTC':'L'}
TripletCount = ddict(lambda:ddict(int))


for key,value in CodonDict.items():
    TripletCount[value][key] += 1
```

Values in `TrpletCount` are defaultdict, you can convert them into lists by something like `map`.